# Merging dictionaries with similar keys but distinct values in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Consider the following dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, double>()
Dictionary<string, double> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, double>()
```

The two dictionaries have the exact same keys, but the values are different. I would like to merge the two dictionaries the following way: Create a new dictionary with the same keys as `dict1` and `dict2`, and where the value is an array composed of the matching value in `dict1`, and the matching value in `dict2`, for each key.

I can easily do that in a loop, but I was hoping there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Any reason for using an array rather than a `Tuple<double, double>` for example?

Comment: what do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not familiar at all with `Tuple` structure, but I am open to using it!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This assumes they really do have the same keys:

```
var merged = dict1.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                pair => new[] { pair.Value, dict2[pair.Key] });
```

Or to create a `Dictionary<string, Tuple<double, double>>`

```
var merged = dict1.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Value, dict2[pair.Key]));
```

Or using an anonymous type to make it cleaner if you're going to use it inside the same method:

```
var merged = dict1.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                pair => new { First = pair.Value,
                                              Second = dict2[pair.Key]) });
```

As noted in comments, these all still loop internally - they won't be more *efficient* than writing the loop yourself, but it's nicer to read.